# Where's exactly the NFC area in the Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: nexus-7, nfc

I've had a Nexus 7 2012 and in the tiny manual there was an indication on where exactly I should touch my phone on it to get NFC communication - near the "e" in the back. That worked great, as I know the NFC area on my Nexus 4 is somewhat in it's middle, but... In a big device like a tablet that's not a guarantee.

However, I have trouble doing the same in the Nexus 7 II. I touch my phone's back to its back but the connection is bad, it comes and goes before I can actually beam stuff... I've tried touching the phone in several different places but didn't get better results.

Where's exactly the NFC touching point on the Nexus 7 II / Nexus 7 2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at a teardown of the new Nexus 7, it looks to be near the center again ([here](http://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/NRxuUxKQcbX2sHPB.huge)
you can see in the photo the NFC is under the inductive charging). iFixit did a pretty good teardown of it [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+7+2nd+Generation+Teardown/16072) which may give you more detail.

Answer (score 5):

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2781895?hl=en):

> If you're using a Nexus 7 and touching its back to another device, make sure the other device is near the "u" in "nexus" to successfully beam content.

"Beam" in this quote is referring to Android Beam, Android's name for NFC content transfer.

Comment: as I said in the question, that's about the original Nexus 7, not the second edition. unfortunatelly I yet can't vote down.

Comment: Why do you believe that statement is referring to the original Nexus 7? I trust them to keep their support documents up to date and therefore believe they're referring to the most current Nexus 7 model. If you think Google Support is incorrect, take it up with Google.

Comment: I won't take this up with Google because it was you who brought it here :)
Besides that, the original Nexus 7 is usually simply called "Nexus 7", while the second generation is explicitly called "Nexus 7 II" or "Nexus 7 2013". Try to look for a pic of the old nexus 7 and you WILL SEE the other answer is right and the page you linked is not about the new device.